# Extracting message from emails, but returning sloppy text passages

Tags: python, html, email, beautifulsoup

So I've created a method to strip an email pages source code of html, style/script tags, and new line tags:

```
def extract_message(url):
    markup = open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]): script.extract()
    text = soup.get_text()
    text_clean = re.sub(r"\n", " ", text)
    text_clean_more = text_clean.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    a = text_clean_more.find('From:')
    print (text_clean[a:])
```

Then, I have it return everything from the instance of 'From:' in the email, all the way to the end of the email. However, after it goes through this process, I get in return a very spaced out and overall sloppy passage of text such as:

[image]

My goal is to print out a clean passage of text. Is there anyway that I could do this? I've been wracking my brain with this for several hours now, and haven't come up with anything rational at all. Just looking for a push in the right direction, Thanks.

Comment: Have you removed tab characters? That could be causing lots of weird spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the module `email` to extract message bodies instead of hacking them apart by hand. Use the module `textwrap` to format message text into nice paragraphs.  This will probably work:

```
paras = rawtext.split("\n\n")  # Split into paragraphs, if any
formatted = "\n\n".join(textwrap.fill(p) for p in paras)
```

But take a look at the [textwrap documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) for keyword options you can specify.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions - Strip Spaces but preserve new lines (or CRLF)